# Average number of people required to find a pair with same birthday

Tags: probability, probability-theory, average, expectation

I have to find the expected number of people required to find a pair with same birthday. This is what I tried:

Assume that there are $M$ possible birthdays, then following the definition for expected number: 
$$E[X] = \sum_{x=2}^{x=M+1} xP[X = x] = \sum_{x=2}^{x=M+1} x \left[  \frac{M!(x-1)}{(M-x+1)! M^{x}} \right]$$

However, this is completely different from what is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people) as .

$$E[X]=1+\sum_{k=1}^{M} \frac{M!}{(M-k)! M^k}.$$

Are these expressions equivalent ? How to prove it ?

Comment: "expected number of people required to find a pair with same birthday" You are not specifying how the experiment is done. Are we picking two people at random each time? Are there a fixed number of people?

Comment: @leonbloy: We have a set of $n$ people with each one having birthday uniformly distributed $\in [1..M]$, Please refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Average_number_of_people this for more information.

Comment: Can you please explain what is X and why $P(X=x)=M!(x-1)/(M-x+1)!M^x$. Or is it somewhere explained so I can check it from there (send link if so)

Comment: X refers to the number of people in the set. $P(X = x)$ is the probability that exactly $x$ people are required to find a pair having same birthday. That will be equal to probability that first $(x-1)$ people have all distinct birthdays and $x$th person has birthday same as one of the previous $(x-1)$ birthdays. So probability that $(x-1)$ people have distinct birthdays = $M!/[(M-x+1)!M^{x-1}]$. And probability that $x$th person has birthday same as one of the previous $(x-1)$ birthdays = $\frac{(x-1)}{M}$. So multiplying the two, you get that expression.

Comment: YOu are not wrong, you can verify numerically that both "completely different" expressions give the same result. To prove that they are equal it's more difficult, that's why the Wikipedia article omits that.

Comment: @leonbloy: Ok, can you state how to obtain the expression mentioned in the wiki ?

Comment: Not presently, but I suggest you to change the question: "Where am I going wrong ?" -> "Are these expressions equivalent? How to prove it"?

Comment: @leonbloy: Thanks, made the edits.

Comment: The formula you link to at Wikipedia is (1 + [what you wrote] ).

Comment: @Ned: Do you mean to say I copied it wrong from the wiki ?

Comment: ok, it's fixed now, sorry, i commented before the latest edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
A = \sum_{x=2}^{M+1} \frac{M!x(x-1)}{(M-x+1)! M^{x}},\qquad
B=\sum_{k=1}^{M} \frac{M!}{(M-k)! M^k}.
$$
Then, using $x-1=M-(M-x+1)$ in the numerators of $A$, one gets $A=C-D$ with
$$
C= \sum_{x=2}^{M+1} \frac{M!x}{(M-x+1)! M^{x-1}},\qquad D=\sum_{x=2}^{M}\frac{M!x}{(M-x)! M^{x}}.
$$
Using $x=M+1-(M-x+1)$ in $C$ and $x=M-(M-x)$ in $D$, one gets $C=E-F$ and $D=G-H$ with
$$
E= \sum_{x=2}^{M+1} \frac{(M+1)!}{(M-x+1)! M^{x-1}},\qquad F=\sum_{x=2}^{M} \frac{M!M}{(M-x)! M^{x}},
$$
and
$$
G=\sum_{x=2}^{M}\frac{M!M}{(M-x)! M^{x}},\qquad H=\sum_{x=2}^{M-1}\frac{M!}{(M-x-1)! M^{x}}.
$$
Using $x=k+1$ in $E$ yields 
$$
E=(M+1)B.
$$
Adding the $x=1$ term in $F=G$ and using $x=k$ yields 
$$
F=G=M(B-1).
$$ 
Using $x=k-1$ in $H$ yields 
$$
H=\sum_{k=3}^{M}\frac{M!M}{(M-k)! M^{k}}=M\left(B-1-\frac{M-1}M\right)=M(B-2)+1.
$$
Thus,
$$
A=E-F-G+H=(M+1)B-2M(B-1)+M(B-2)+1=1+B.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You can just use this formula for the expected value https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Formula_for_non-negative_random_variables

$$\operatorname{E}[X]=\sum _{k=1}^\infty \operatorname{P}(X\geq k).$$

In your case X is the random variable "first person to have a repeated birthday". We know that $$P(X\geq 1)=1$$ $$P(X\geq M+2)=0 $$ $$P(X\geq k+1)= \frac{M!}{(M-k)! M^k}$$ 
and we can easily deduce the wanted formula
$$
E[X] = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{M} \frac{M!}{(M-k)!M^k}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can also get the second expression using linearity of expected value.

Let $X_i$ be the random variable which is $1$ if there was no pair among first $(i-1)$ persons having same birthday(which hence implies that $i$th person is needed) and $0$ otherwise.Then:
$$X = \sum_{i=1}^{M+1} X_i$$ Using linearity of expected value:

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{M+1} E[X_i] = \sum_{i=1}^{M+1} \Pr[X_i = 1]$$
Now $\Pr[X_i = 1]$ will simply be equal to the probability the we have a sequence of $(i-1)$ distinct birthdays. 
$$\Pr[X_i = 1] = \frac{M!}{(M-i+1)!M^{i-1}}$$Substituting in the above expression, we get:
$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{M+1} \frac{M!}{(M-i+1)!M^{i-1}}$$
Using $k = i - 1$ and starting the sum from $i=1$ yields:
$$E[X] = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{M} \frac{M!}{(M-k)!M^k}$$ which is the required expression.